# DotnetCore project IntermediateOutputPath leaves some files in the solution directory

Tags: build, .net-core, project

In order to keep the repository clean and separated from output and build files we change corresponding paths in the project file.

For Net Framework project specifying **IntermediateOutputPath** redirects the obj directory to the corresponding folder.

For Net Core project (3.0) using this property is not sufficient. Whereas Debug, Release folders are indeed redirected, the **obj** folder is still created and it contains some file - such as 
*project.assets.json, .csproj.nuget.cache, .csproj.nuget.dgspec.json,.csproj.nuget.g.props, .csproj.nuget.g.targets* .
Using **BaseIntermediateOutputPath** - doesnt help either.

Just wonder if someone can suggest how to move the whole obj directory?
Thanks

The Solution suggested by Martin works fine for Net Core projects

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDIrectory>C:\Temp\Build\$(Configuration)</BuildDIrectory>
    <RelativePath>some arelative path which depends on location of corresponding project withing the solution</RelativePath>

    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(BuildDIrectory)\obj\$(RelativePath)\$(AssemblyName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDIrectory)\out\$(RelativePath)\$(AssemblyName)\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>$(BuildDIrectory)\Documentation\$(RelativePath)\$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  ...
  </Project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BaseIntermediateOutputPath` works as well, but it needs to be set very early in order to take effect.

The easiest way would be to add it to a `Directory.Build.props` file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\shared-obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If you want to specify it directly in the csproj file, you cannot use the `<Project Sdk="` notation since the property needs to be set before parts of the SDK are applied. However it works when using explicit SDK imports and correct ordering:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>..\shared-obj\myprojA\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! The second part with the project property is a good solution for me. I tried to upvote your answer but as I have less than 15 reputations it was recorded but was not taken into account :(

Comment: If the solution works for you, consider marking the answer as accepted (checkmark icon). And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Dear Martin, stackoverflow users
following this approach I encountered some strange problem - one of Nuget packages got lost. There is something specific to this package as other package is displayed under Dependencies/Packages but one is not. I can see in the Output that it has been succesfully installed. But it is now in the list and if I try to use classes defined in that package they are not recongnized. Yet if I change the .csproj file to the standard one 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
...
the Nuget appears in the Solutoin Explorer and classes are recognized.

Comment: Any idea why it happens and how it cam be fixed?
Thanks,
arbus

Comment: Maybe open a new question with a more detailed description (csproj content)

Comment: hi Martin
created
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502644/dotnetcore-project-with-changed-intermediateoutputpath-some-nuget-packages-are